# Render dynamic content using tabs with react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm developing an app where I need to render different content depending on the active tab.

I've been trying different types of conditional rendering but nothing is working.

Here's my code at the moment:

```js
handleTab = tab => {
        const { news } = this.state.news;
        const { categories } = this.props;
        const filtered = categories.filter(
            category => category.tags.includes(tab.toLowerCase())
        );
        if(tab === 'Codigos'){
            this.setState({ active: tab});
            return <Content1 />;
        }
        if(tab === 'Servicios'){
            this.setState({ active: tab });
            return <Content2 />;
        }
        if(tab === 'Noticias'){
            this.setState({ active: tab});
            return <Content3 />;
        }
    };


renderTab(tab) {
        const { active } = this.state;
        const isActive = active === tab;

        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                key={`tab-${tab}`}
                onPress={() => this.handleTab(tab)}
                style={[
                    styles.tab,
                    isActive ? styles.active : null
                ]}
            >
                <Text size={16} medium gray={!isActive} secondary={isActive}>
                    {tab}
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
render() {
        const { profile, navigation } = this.props;
        const { categories } = this.state;
        const tabs = ['Tab1', 'Tab2', 'Tab3'];

        return (
            <Block>
                <Block flex={false} row center space="between" style={styles.header}>
                    <Text h1 bold>Explorar</Text>
                    <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Settings')}>
                        <Image
                            source={profile.avatar}
                            style={styles.avatar}
                        />
                    </Button>
                </Block>

                <Block flex={false} row style={styles.tabs}>
                    {tabs.map(tab => this.renderTab(tab))}
                </Block>



            </Block>
        )
    }
```

Right now I can render the tabs and set the active tab but I can't render the content for each tab.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're returning the component in `handleTab()` which is used in `onPress` handler **not** in render.

This should be:

```
setTab = tab => {
 this.setState({
   tab,
 });
}

handleTab = () => {
  const { tab } = this.state;
  if(tab === 'Codigos'){
    return <Content1 />;
  }
  // other conditions
}

// renderTab(tab)
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => this.setTab(tab)} // <--- Set active tab
>
  <Text size={16} medium gray={!isActive} secondary={isActive}>
    {this.handleTab()} // <---- Render the returned component
  </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

*Other parts of the code are omitted for brevity.*